# Different resource folders for separate tablet & mobile APKs

Tags: android, mobile, apk, tablet

I am building an app that has two APKs: one for tablets and the other for mobiles.

The tablet version won't use the drawable of the mobile APK and vice versa.

I want to do this because of APK size.

Can anyone give me pointers how to achieve this?

I tried to use flavors for this but it can make the two APK.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Comment: Whats the need of creating two apks, if you can create separate layouts for phone and tablet?

Comment: @Sanoop by making the separate layout for phone and table. it will increase the size of the apk.

Comment: Creating separate layouts is the most appropriate way.

Comment: @VivekMishra but by making the separate layout it increase the size of the apk. because if intstall the apk of tablet it also install the layout of mobile.

Comment: Same goes for the images too. They will also be installed both devices

Comment: @VivekMishra so this is the problem. i hope u understand very well. so i don't want it. i want when user install the apk for the mobile the layout and images for the tablet does not installed,.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible and moreover how will you manage your layout properly for tablets and phone without creating different layouts?

Comment: @VivekMishra so according to you this is not possible. i think you won't understand my question completely now. i am making two separate layout for both tablet and mobile. but i don't want that when i install the app in mobile the layout and images of the tablet also installed and vice versa.

Comment: Exactly how much does the APK grow by having both layouts within one app?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen can you tell me is this possible or not ??

Comment: I have edited your question to improve the grammar to help make it easier to understand.  I am not sure about the last paragraph though; it seems you mean to say "I tried to use flavors for this but it **can't** make the two APKs" but, since an edit to this effect would drastically change your original question I haven't made that edit too.  If my suspicion is correct please can you edit the question yourself to say "can't make the two APKs"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android Flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) for this purpose.

```
android {
   ...
   defaultConfig {...}
   buildTypes {...}
   productFlavors {
       tablet {
           applicationIdSuffix ".tablet"
           versionNameSuffix "-tablet"
       }
       phone {
           applicationIdSuffix ".phone "
           versionNameSuffix "-phone "
       }
   }
```

}

Each flavor will create separate build folders,where you can place resource files you wish to override. Here is an excellent tutorial:
[Mastering "Product Flavors" on Android](http://blog.brainattica.com/how-to-work-with-flavours-on-android/)

Comment: sir, i tried this by the flavor already. but it create the two build.i mean i want package name same. by this it intstall two apk with different package name.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, as Google play store providing support for multiple apks. 
You can check here for more details- 
[Creating Multiple APKs for Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/screensize.html)

Comment: by this it takes the image and layout of the tablet in the tablet and not will take the images and layout of the mobile.