# How to make one APK for the both mobile and tablet?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, apk, tablet

I want to make only one APK for mobile and tablet both. but i want that when user install the app for the mobile the layout and images of the tablet should not be installed.and same for the tablet when user install the app for the tablet the layout and images of the mobile should not be installed.

```
Can anyone tell me how can i do this ?? any help would be apperciated.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to make different apk for tablet and mobile that one use one resources folder and the another apk use another resource folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090052/i-want-to-make-different-apk-for-tablet-and-mobile-that-one-use-one-resources-fo)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen its not dupplicate. that is also my question. i did not get any answer. thatswhy i putting again. please if you know how can i do this then please tell me. it is urgent.

Answer (score 0):

**I think don't try that**

when use the images into project Android studio Create assets and compile them into all Layout and when user install apk, android install all of them but use specific layout by device property.

Comment: but by this all the images and layout are installed in the apk. i want that for the tablet only tablet layout and images are installed. and vice versa.